# Can I form a C++ reference from a pointer of the wrong type?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

If I have a pointer `T* t` and I use `reinterpret_cast<T*>(&u)` to point to some object `u` (which is not a T), I know that I cannot access `u` via `t`.

Therefore, I think that I cannot form `T& rt` *from* `t`, even if I *don't* perform any access through `rt` because:

1. To form `rt` I would need to express `*t` in some way, which is an "access", and I am prohibited from doing this.
2. I would be initializing a reference with something other than "a valid object".

Is this understanding correct?

(Edited to clarify that I am asking about whether `rt` can be formed from `t`.)

Comment: You can use `reinterpret_cast<t&>(u)` to get a reference, with the same stipulations such that you can't really do anything with it except cast it back.

Comment: Yes, but if I am given only the pointer (by some C API, for example), I am "stuck" dealing with pointers.  I can never get an "wrong type reference" from the "wrong type pointer", I think.  I've edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To form rt I would need to express *t in some way, which is an "access", and I am prohibited from doing this.

No, dereferencing itself is not an access. An access would require reading from or writing to a scalar object.

> I would be initializing a reference with something other than "a valid object".

If `t` points to an object (whether with the correct type or not), there is nothing prohibiting binding a reference to the lvalue `*t`.

However, you must assure that `t` does actually point to an object. Specifically you need to assure that `u` is aligned suitably for the type `T`. Otherwise the result of `reinterpret_cast<T*>(&u)` will have an unspecified value, instead of pointing to `u` (or an object pointer-interconvertible with it) as expected.

In any case, of course, you are not generally allowed to use the resulting reference to read from or write to the object, to access members, etc.

Comment: How about if the original  type is not correctly aligned for the target reference type? Must the conversion still be well-formed?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "Dereferencing a pointer to an object of the wrong type is prohibited" Can you provide  citation?

Comment: @Useless Aren't you referring to what I mentioned in the answer? "_Specifically you need to assure that u is aligned suitably for the type T._". In the comment above I was talking about indirection of `t` after the conversion, assuming it points to an object. Or am I missing a nuance?

Comment: @user17732522 Retracted my comment. After looking into it more, you are right that this is different.

Comment: Thanks.  I was misled by [_A reference is required to be initialized to refer to a valid object or function_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) and reading \[dcl.init.ref\] didn't really clarify things for me.  I was also conflating this was the prohibition on things like `&*container.begin()` (when the returned iterator is singular), but that's different because "there is no object there", roughly speaking.  In my case, alignment is not an issue.

Comment: @BradSpencer You would still be initializing the reference with a (valid) object, just not an object of the same type as in the reference type. I don't think there is anything prohibiting that, although it is not something one usually would do. Basically the only thing the reference can be used for is casting it back to the original type and conventionally one would use `void*` in a situation that requires passing a type-erased pointer/reference. `&*container.begin()` would be disallowed simply because the preconditions for the container say that `*` may not be applied to the end iterator.

Comment: @BradSpencer But if the container is e.g. just an array with raw pointers as iterators, then yes, the end iterator would be a past-the-object pointer, which is a distinct kind of pointer value from pointer values pointing to objects. These can't be dereferenced.

Comment: @user17732522 I agree it's unusual.  I basically have some orthogonal reasons for wanting to mix in with an existing overload set, so `T&` happens to work much better than `void*` or even `T*`, here.

Comment: @user17732522 you're absolutely right, I didn't spot that you'd stipulated alignment.

Comment: It may be worth noting that *as a practical matter*, when targeting platforms that don't support unaligned access, clang will sometimes use the fact that a pointer type requires alignment to infer that functions like `memcpy` can be replaced with a sequence of aligned loads and stores.  Even if `int*` and `char*` have the same representation, that doesn't mean that a `char*` can be round-tripped through an `int*`.

Comment: @supercat I understand your first sentence.  I don't understand how your second sentence follows from your first.  Can you explain?  Or are they two separate thoughts?

Comment: @BradSpencer: The C and C++ Standards were written to describe *existing* languages where many constructs had meaningful behaviors on platforms where data types had compatible representations, but might behave unpredictably on some others.  Until about 2005, many questions about whether various constructs invoked UB were recognized as being of only "theoretical" importance: if someone were to build a sufficiently unusual hardware platform, a construct might behave weirdly, but there was no reason to think anyone would do such a thing.  Since about 2005, however, ...

Comment: ...compilers have become increasingly aggressive at identifying situations where the Standard doesn't require that they behave meaningfully, and exploiting them in ways that might be useful for some tasks, but dangerous and counter-productive for others.  I don't think there's any way to describe all of the situations where casting an unaligned `char*` to an `int*` *whose value is never used to access storage as anything other than a character type* might plausibly cause erroneous behavior.

Comment: @supercat I think you're explaining that the second sentence is an independent thought.  Thanks!  That helps, and my knowledge of the circumstances aligns with your retelling.